# save a sound file in specific folder using matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, record, wav

I'm recording a sound and using `wavwrite` to save the `wav` file, but I need to save it in a specific folder in `C:`, such as in `c:\Users\soundwav`.

Here is an excerpt from my `wavwrite` code:

```
data(:,s)=getdata(ai,44100); 
y = [y; data]
         format shortg
         c = clock;
         fix(c);
         a=num2str(c);
         year=strcat(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5));
         month=strcat(a(19),a(20));
         day=strcat(a(34),a(35));
         hour=strcat(a(48),a(49));
         min=strcat(a(63),a(64));
         sec=strcat(a(74),a(75));
         name=strcat(year,'-',month,'-',day,'-',hour,'-',min,'-',sec);
         wavwrite(data,name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cd the path while saving it. I have included a line that concatenates the full path with name variable and then saves it.

```
         data(:,s)=getdata(ai,44100); 
         y = [y; data]
         format shortg
         c = clock;
         fix(c);
         a=num2str(c);
         year=strcat(a(1),a(2),a(3),a(4),a(5));
         month=strcat(a(19),a(20));
         day=strcat(a(34),a(35));
         hour=strcat(a(48),a(49));
         min=strcat(a(63),a(64));
         sec=strcat(a(74),a(75));
         name=strcat(year,'-',month,'-',day,'-',hour,'-',min,'-',sec);
         name = strcat('c:\Users\soundwav\', name);
         wavwrite(data,name);
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the folder in which to save your file, you can use `uigetdir` which allows you to select the folder; then you can add to it the filename you've built.

```
directoryname = uigetdir
```

You can also specify a starting folder

```
directoryname = uigetdir('c:\user\')

name = strcat(directoryname, '\', name);
```

Hope this helps.